# Adding new child's to HTML DOM with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

I have block of HTML like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child_1"></div>
    <div id="child_2"></div>
    <div id="child_3"></div>
    <div id="child_4"></div>
</div>
```

i want to be able to do this with Angular.js:

1- find a child with id and add new child `before` or `after` that

2- remove a child element by finding id(free it's memory too)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @javierfdezg: i didn't because everything i found in the web can't solve this for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is through JQuery or Plain Javascript, Angular isn't really able to select your HTML DOM elements if they are not instantiated by Angular itself. 
I would go with simple Jquery ...

---

Add child after :

```
$(#id).after('<div> New Child </div>')
```

---

Or before:

```
$(#id).before('<div> New Child before </div>')
```

---

Remove :

```
$('#id').remove()
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the help of javascript

1- find a child with id and add new child before or after that

```
var elem=document.createElement('div');
elem.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
```

2- remove a child element by finding id(free it's memory too)

```
var child=document.getElementById('uniqueIdentifier');
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with Angular you will have to use [directives](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/index.html).

Here is an snippet of code from the [Angular doc](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js//directives/repeatedly-rendering-directives-dom-node-children.html):

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive("repeatNtimes", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
      var content = tElement.children();
      for (var i=1; i<attrs.repeat; i++) {
        tElement.append(content.clone());
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the AngularJS documentation. Specially on ng-repeat, if it can help you.
More, try to attribute a JS function to you div parent.
But a little query Google could help you, if you try.

Comment: try to do things in `angular way` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: ng-repeat is Angular way ^^. when i say 'JS function' I mean 'a function from your JS file'. So it can be made in Angular way.